# Extract value from column containing dicts in a few rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a nested json file that I convert to a Pandas Dataframe:

```
tabell = pd.DataFrame.from_records(r.response['trades'])
```

It looks like this:

```
id instrument price initialUnits  takeProfitOrder                                      
0 AUD_CAD  0.90  10000  NaN
1 AUD_CAD  0.89  10000  {'id': '379895', 'createTime': '2020-06-15T12:...
```

I want to extract the 'id' field from the inner dict, and keep that as the value in that column.

If I write this, it works:

```
tabell.loc[1]['takeProfitOrder'] = tabell.loc[1]['takeProfitOrder']['id']
```

However, I do not know which rows, and it is thousands. Therefore I do not want to iterate with a loop.

But if I just write, which is what I want, it fails:

```
tabell['takeProfitOrder'] = tabell['takeProfitOrder']['id']
```

Obviously it fails at the first line, as it contains 'NaN' instead of a dict.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this. This operation needs to be done a lot of times on relatively large datasets. Therefore, I need an efficient way of accomplishing it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) for possible processing missing values:

```
tabell['takeProfitOrder'] = tabell['takeProfitOrder'].str.get('id')
```

Comment: Thanks. That works.  I had already tried tabell['takeProfitOrder'] = tabell['takeProfitOrder'].get('id') and it did not work. Did not think about the .str

Comment: First time saw .str.get in action. Good stuff cheers